# Pass an array of strings from VB6 to a COM object

Tags: vb6, atl

I'm using ATL do create a COM wrapper around a DLL.  For some functions, I need to pass an array of strings.  How would I set up the IDL so that intellisense in VB6 will show the parameter as 'String()' instead of just 'String' or 'Variant()'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

`[in, out] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* inout_asParam`

Comment: That's what I thought.  So why do I get errors when I use:  
  
`[id(2), helpstring("method StartupInitialization")] HRESULT StartupInitialization([in] LONG argc, [in] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* argv, [in] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* argE, [out,retval] IWorkArea** WA);`  
  
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'  
error C2059: syntax error : ')'  
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'